# Can We Improve Query Performance by Unifying Columns?

Tags: mysql

We are working on a database for examination system with a large Number of Questions in it,so i have "QTable" with this columns:

**QuestionNum | BookID | BookSeason | QuestionType** and ...

Consider that we need to select some questions with BookID=5 and BookSeason=11 and QuestionType=2

Which idea is better to improve querying performance:

1-`Select * from QTable where BookID=5 and BookSeason=11 and QuestionType=2;`

**or**

2-**unifying BookID and BookSeason and QuestionType into QuestionID like this:**

**QuestionID = "000000"(QuestionNum) + "000"(BookID) + "00"(BookSeason) + "0"(QuestionType)**

An example for QestionID: "01253305112"  (012533 is QuestionNum, 05 is BookID, 11 is BookSeason, 2 is QuestionType)

Now the query to select some questions with BookID=5 and BookSeason=11 and QuestionType=2 will be like this:

`Select * from QTable where QuestionID LIKE '------05112'`;

Any better ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to combine columns.  A column should contain a "unitary" value, not some complicated code that is cumbersome to understand.

For this query:

```
Select * 
from QTable
where BookID = 5 and BookSeason = 11 and QuestionType = 2;
```

You want an index on `QTable(BookID, BookSeason, QuestionType)`.  The same index will work, for just looking for `BookId` or for `BookId` and `BookSeason`.

Comment: thanks for answering,
but i wanna know which one has **better performance** in query

Comment: @KyleMarriot . . . Index lookups using equality on three keys versus one key should pretty much have the same performance.  It could go either way, but I would guess that 3 integer comparisons are faster than one string comparison, because of the collation issues.